# New-ADUser unable to concatanate name and domainname

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to create userprincipalname as combination of username and hardcoded domainname

csv file:

```
name,displayname,givenname,surname
dhall,Don Hall,Don,Hall
```

Code:

```
Import-csv "c:\output.csv" | ForEach-Object {new-aduser -name $_.name -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@{1}" -f $_.name,"Dev.domain.Net") -DisplayName "$($_.givenname $_.surname)" -givenName $_.givenname -surname $_.surname -path "OU=Workspaces,DC=Dev,DC=domain,DC=Net" -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring passs -asplaintext -force) -Enabled  [System.Convert]::toboolean($true)) -ChangePasswordAtLogon ([system.convert]::ToBoolean($true))}
```

And getting:

```
At line:1 char:159
+ ...  -f $_.name,"Dev.domain.Net") -DisplayNa
+
Unexpected token '$_' in expression or stateme
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:)
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Tried also `-UserPrincipalName ([string]::Concat($_.name,"@dev.domain.net"))`
but same error

```
PS C:\>  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  1944
```

Windows server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's causing that error (don't have an AD controller to test against at the moment so can't validate) but in cases where I'm going to need to reuse a property multiple times I tend to assign it to a temporary variable (makes it slightly easier to write the code and don't run into issues with the pipeline variable getting updated).

```powershell
Import-CSV "c:\output.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.name
    $upn  = "{0}@{1}" -f $name,"dev.domain.net"
    New-ADUser -Name $name -UserPrincipalName $upn #...
}
```

Comment: didn't have time to answer before: yes, this works, thanks !!